# Looking for a manhwa where the main character was pushed off building/balcony in previous life

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m looking for a manhwa where, in her past life, the main character was pushed off a balcony right as she got a text saying she got into her dream school. A woman pushed her off after asking her some sort of question.

At the end she and the male lead end up on a train, and they talk to the woman that pushes her.

Answer (score 3):

This is *[The Reason Why Raeliana Ended up at the Duke's Mansion](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-reason-why-raeliana-ended-up-at-the-dukes-mansion)*. It is licensed by [Tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/raeliana).

> Poisoned to death by her own betrothed?! Eunha didn’t wake up in a novel’s story just to get killed off again as an unfortunate extra! To change her story she needs a cover… 6 months pretending to be the fake fiancée of the novel's male protagonist, Duke Noah Wynknight. But will this cold-hearted, angel-faced demon of a man really help her avoid another ill-fated ending?!

The first chapter includes the scene you describe; in her past life, she's standing on a rooftop and talking to a someone, but can't recall what she looked like or what they were talking about. She gets a text stating that she got into university, and is pushed off.

[image]

She then reincarnates within a story she read.

The ending includes a scene where she and the male lead are on a train and she talks to the goddess that pushed her off.